# How to position change flutter TextFormField prefix icon?

Tags: flutter

I have tried to change TextFormField prefix icon positions but I don't understand how to do it anyone has a any idea I'm used code as below

```js
child: TextFormField(
  autocorrect: false,
  maxLines: 4,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: new BorderSide(
            style: BorderStyle.solid)),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.1)),
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.edit),
    hintText: "Onion 1kg",
    labelText: 'Item Description (Optional)',
  ),
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(25, 25, 35, 1),
    fontSize:18,
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: what is exactly you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are trying to change the icon position in your `TextFormField` to right position, so just use `suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.edit),` instead of `prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.edit),` so your code will be come like below:

```
child: TextFormField(
  autocorrect: false,
  maxLines: 4,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: new BorderSide(
            style: BorderStyle.solid)),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.1)),
    //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.edit), // this is left side
      suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.edit), // this is right side.
    hintText: "Onion 1kg",
    labelText: 'Item Description (Optional)',
  ),
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(25, 25, 35, 1),
    fontSize:18,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prefixIcon: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 20),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/user-form-icon.svg",
                        ), // myIcon is a 48px-wide widget.
                      ),
```

Does this try what you want? Or you can use

```
prefix: Container () directly
```